# MSAccess: Formatting substring in a textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I fear I may already know the answer to this, but here goes:

I have a textbox on a form, bound to a table.  I'd like to highlight or otherwise format a single word in this textbox.   I know the position and length of the substring in question.  Ican accomplish this in EXCEL already.

THIS IS A **SAMPLE** STRING

I had thought to add some sort of formatting tag to the data, then interpret on the form, muck like the tags used in this forum using some "reserved" characters (like the enclosing ** on this forum).

THIS IS A ** SAMPLE ** STRING

Possible with stock textbox control?

Thanks for any ideas.

Mark

Comment: thx, removed offending request - mark

Comment: The following link describes how to implemet a RTF text box in Access: https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Insert-or-add-a-rich-text-field-9f86237d-dbbc-4a85-b12c-9d8dca824630?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Wayne, very encouraging!  Unfortunately I don't seem to have the RichTx32.ocx installed on my machine.  Off to locate.  - also my devt machine is 64Bit.

Comment: I'm running Vista (gasp!) with Office 2010 and found it in a CAB file named ProPrWW.cab. Possibly when you installed Office you may not have installed ALL components? (I generally install ALL options for any products I will use)

Comment: I too install all components (minus some wizards-related stuff).  I checked the Office/Access install...there are none "unchecked", though clearly this OCX is missing.  I did find the OCX online and installed (as admin), seemingly successfully, but still not listed among the ActiveX objects.  I do not see that CAB on my system.

Comment: Did you register it also?